# How to place a custom control inside the map div in ol3?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I'm sorry, this question is irrelevant to ol3 and there were some evident code errors (Note from the author)**

I'm rewriting a Ol 2 map application with the most recent version of Openlayers 3.15.1. I need to add custom controls to manipulate sea surface temperature maps. I want to place the custom controls over the map . However after trying to recreate the code of some examples showing how to write custom controls with Ol3, I have found some drawbacks to correctly recreate it.

The custom control is composed by a small icon and clicking over it does some stutf. Here below I show several versions of the code used. Basically the controls are created by a function that loads initially.

Only one of them works properly and I would like to understand why the others do not. All examples are almost equivalent two are with pure javascript and two with JQuery trying to look for a optimal solution.

**Code 1**: Pure Javascript but using innerHTML to insert the image into a . The image seems to be not inserted into the DOM.

```
var texto = "<img id=\"tool_draw\" src=\"/js/Saidin/Image/draw_line_off.png\">";
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML=texto;
element.className = 'ol-unselectable ol-mycontrol';
element.style.position="absolute";
element.style.width="24px";
element.style.top= "70px";
element.style.left= "9px";;

var action= function(e){ alert('hola'); }

document.getElementById("tool_draw").addEventListener("click", action, false);

var okk= new ol.control.Control({
    element:element
  });

map.addControl(okk);
```

**This code does not work. The error is: *document.getElementById(...) is null***

**Code 2**: Pure Javascript but creating the image with the constructor and that's all!

```
var texto =  "/js/Saidin/Image/draw_line_off.png";
var boton = document.createElement('img');
boton.src=texto;
boton.className = 'ol-unselectable ol-mycontrol';
boton.setAttribute("id","tool_draw");
boton.style.position="absolute";
boton.style.top= "70px";
boton.style.left= "9px";

var action= function(e){ alert('hola'); }

boton.addEventListener("click", action, false);

var okk= new ol.control.Control({
   element:boton
});

map.addControl(okk);
```

**This code works fine !**

**Code 3**: I think is Equivalent to Code 1 but using JQuery library

```
var texto ="<img id=\"tool_draw\" src=\"/js/Saidin/Image/draw_line_off.png\">";
$('body').append($('<div/>', {
    id:'hola',
    'class' : 'ol-unselectable ol-mycontrol',
    texto:texto,
    css: { "position":"absolute","top": "70px", "left":"9px" }
}));

element=$('#hola');
var cont= function(e){ alert('hola'); }

$("#tool_draw").on('click', cont );

var okk= new ol.control.Control({
   element:element
});

map.addControl(okk);
```

**This code does not work. The error is: *TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node.*.**

**Code 4**: I think is equivalent to Code 2 but using JQuery library

```
var element=$('<img>', {
id:'tool_draw',
src:'/js/Saidin/Image/draw_line_off.png',
'class' : 'ol-unselectable ol-mycontrol',
 css: { "position":"absolute","top": "70px", "left":"9px" }
 });

$('#map').append(element);
var cont= function(e){ alert('hola'); }

element.on('click', cont );

var okk= new ol.control.Control({
     element:element
});

map.addControl(okk);
```

**This code works fine ! but... the same error from ol.js appear *TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node.***

Can somebody explain me what's wrong with the failing codes ?. I apologize for this long question and I'm not sure if the problem comes from JQuery, JavaScript or is related with the new OL3 version. Any explanation is welcome !. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. code1 doesnt work cause you use `getElementById` while the element is not ready on dom. You may use `element.addEventListener("click", action, false);` but I am not sure if it would work.
2. Code 2 works cause you attach the listener directly to the element (like the way I suggest on 1) and you are not searching for it in the DOM (`getElementById`)
3. Code 3 doesnt work cause  appendChild is a native DOM method and only accepts DOM nodes as a parameter. The element you're trying to append (`$('body').append($('<div/>'.....`) is a jQuery object, not a DOM element.
4. Code 4 shouldnt work for the same reason as 3.

Your problems have nothing to do with ol3. It is jquery & js problems. Hope  I helped you a bit

Comment: I'm very sorry to waste your time. I finally realize there were some typos in the code, particularly in Code 2, the `texto:texto` attribute was wrong !,changing it to `html:texto` was the error. The code 3 is finally correct with the append() JQuery method. You are right the problems have nothing to do with ol3, i apologize and I will edit the question title to not confuse people. Thank you anyway !